# FATAL ERROR luaotfload | load : × Failed to load "fontloader" module "basics-gen" on Debian Bullseye (livetex-full package)

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tex-core, lualatex-dev, docker

I am hoping a LuaTeX/LaTeX expert can assit on this issue I am having.

I have a docker container that is running on Debian Bullseye and I have installed the `textlive-full` [package](https://packages.debian.org/stable/tex/texlive-full). The full instalation is as follows:

```
apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y wget perl-tk fonts-noto-cjk "texlive-full=2020.20210202-3" &&
apt-get clean
```

The .tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tipa}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={System},
            pdfproducer={System},
            pdfcreator={System}
            }

\newcommand{\cvspace}{\vskip 1.2em}

\overfullrule=0pt

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Field COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\field}[2]{
\columnratio{0.20}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \noindent\hspace{0pt}\textbf{#1} \switchcolumn \noindent{#2}
\end{paracol}
\cvspace
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Indent Field COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\indentfield}[2]{
\columnratio{0.30}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\baselineskip=1pt
\hspace{0pt}\textbf{#1} \switchcolumn \noindent{#2}
\end{paracol}
\cvspace
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Text COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\text}[1]{
\noindent{#1}
\cvspace
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   header
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Force new page%
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   graphic COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\graphic}[1]{
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{#1}
\end{center}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   allgraphic COMMAND
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\allgraphic}[1]{
\begin{center}
    \saveimageresource{#1}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages}{
    \includegraphics[page=\i,width=0.48\textwidth]{#1}
    }
\end{center}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   url
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue}
\urlstyle{same}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   section end
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\drawline}{\hrule \cvspace}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   New Paragraph
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\newpara}[0]{\\[3mm]}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Table Headings
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\tableheadings}[1]{#1 \\}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Table Row
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\tablerow}[1]{\hline #1 \\}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Support Content Wrapping
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\wraptext[1]{\tokcycle
  {\addcytoks{##1\penalty0\hskip0pt plus1pt\relax}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {#1}\the\cytoks}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Support for CJK Languages
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\directlua {
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk", {
    Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR:mode=harf;script=hang;",
    Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC:mode=harf;script=hani;",
    Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=kana;",
    Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP:mode=harf;script=hira;",
  })
  luaotfload.add_multiscript("cjk_bold", {
    Hang = "Noto Serif CJK KR/B:mode=harf;script=hang;",
    Hani = "Noto Serif CJK TC/B:mode=harf;script=hani;",
    Kana = "Noto Serif CJK JP/B:mode=harf;script=kana;",
    Hira = "Noto Serif CJK JP/B:mode=harf;script=hira;",
  })
}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={multiscript=cjk},BoldFeatures={RawFeature={multiscript=cjk_bold}}]{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
% Above this line is standard and included in base.tex%s
\title{MainTitle}\author{SubTitle}\date{SubSubTitle}\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Then when I try to generate a PDF from a tex file with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/lualatex -halt-on-error -jobname output -output-format pdf output.tex
```

I get the following error in logs:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2023.3.10)  10 MAR 2023 12:56
 restricted system commands enabled.
**/app/working/latex_abcde12345_64609089851690_4946691330391035353/output.tex
(/app/working/latex_abcde12345_64609089851690_4946691330391035353/output.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load "fontloader" module "basics-gen".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "/etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.l
ua:301: system : no writeable cache path, quiting"./etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaot
fload/luaotfload-init.lua:301: system : no writeable cache path, quiting
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:301: in function 'os.exi
t'
    /etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:203: in local 'load_fontloade
r_module'
    /etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:303: in upvalue 'init_ma
in'
    /etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:590: in function 'luaotf
load-init.lua'
    /etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:322: in field 'main'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
<everyjob> ...ring \\def\string \\encodingdefault{OT1}')end }
                                                  \let \f@encoding \encoding...
l.1 
  \documentclass[a4paper,16pt]{article}

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 8 strings out of 478824
 100000,383344 words of node,token memory allocated
 275 words of node memory still in use:
   1 hlist, 1 dir, 39 glue_spec nodes
   avail lists: 2:12,3:1,4:1
 19793 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 22 fonts using 2516239 bytes
 5i,0n,1p,114b,15s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The only way I have managed to get this to work is by installing `install-tl-20200406` manually following the steps [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). However, this installation process can take a very long time (up to two hours), ideally, I want it to be very quick, within a couple of minutes.

Is there a way I can make this template .tex file to work, the installation process quicker, and use Debian packages to make it work without the manual installation?

Note:
When going through the manual installtion, I was doing the following:

```
RUN chmod -R +x /install-tl-20200406
RUN echo "I" | /install-tl-20200406/install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2020/tlnet-final
RUN chmod -R +x /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/
RUN rm -rf /install-tl-20200406
RUN chmod o+w /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var
```

Comment: you are running a luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 on a texlive 2020? That looks quite odd (but I have no idea about debian installations). Unrelated but don't use T1-fontenc and inputenc with lualatex. The tipa package is dubious too.

Comment: Which version of luaotfload should I be using for texlive 2020? The 2020 version seems like it's coming from the Debian package which then is the problem. How could I specify which version of luaotfload to use?

Comment: well the version should at least fit. Mixing versions from different sources and ages is not a good idea. How should anyone be able to debug such a mix for you? Personally I use lualatex on windows with a current texlive 2023 (currently pretest but will be released soon).

Comment: unrelated to the error but don't  use either of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex

Comment: @root92 As part of the `texlive-full` package you already installed a version of luaotfload (under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload`) which should match that version. You additionally have a much newer version of luaotfload under `/etc/texmf/tex/lualatex/luaotfload` which doesn't match your remaining system. Even if this doesn't cause your current error that's an unsupported and highly fragile setup which is likely to cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I was able to resolve the issue and it appeared to be a permission issue. Using the texlive-luatex Debian package I needed to provide the Docker user permission to `/var/lib/texmf` after that, it started working and no longer got the error.

Thank you @David Carlisle and @Ulrike Fischer regarding the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` these have been removed.